# Are there more non-Hamiltonian graph than Hamiltonian on n vertices?

Tags: graph-theory, asymptotics, hamiltonian-path

A Hamiltonian graph contains a Hamiltonian cycle. A non-Hamiltonian does not contain any Hamiltonian cycle. For every positive integer n are there more non-Hamiltonian graph than Hamiltonian on n vertices?

I found this link:

[Maximum number of edges in a non-Hamiltonian graph](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/91975/maximum-number-of-edges-in-a-non-hamiltonian-graph)

Maybe this could be useful

Comment: I think you mean to say, "For every positive integer $n$ are there more ..."  What are your thoughts on this?  What have you done so far?

Comment: Thanks. I fixed and I put a link that might help us

Comment: Take a look at [Probability of choosing a random graph with a Hamilton cycle](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1113613/probability-of-choosing-a-graph-with-hamiltonian-cycle)

Comment: How can we translate that? Would that mean there are more Hamiltonian when n tends to infinity?

Comment: Yes, it means that as $n$ goes to infinity, almost all the $n-$vertex graphs (labeled graphs, actually) are Hamiltonian.

Comment: My last comment wasn't very good.  When $p=\frac12,$ every labelled graph has the same probability of being chosen, so the probability that a labeled graph is Hamiltonian is equal to the fraction of labeled graphs that are Hamiltonian.

Comment: Thanks. Can this be applied to unlabeled graphs as well?

Comment: @saulspatz With that approach, you would want the probability to be less than $\frac{1}{n!}$ that a uniformly random labeled graph is not Hamiltonian, which is false.

Comment: @MishaLavrov Yes, you're right.  I just did it in my head -- I should have written it down.  Is there an easy way to see that the result carries over from labeled graphs to (isomorphism classes of) graphs?

Comment: @saulspatz Almost all random graphs have trivial automorphism group. (See, e.g., [Theorem 3.1 in this paper](https://people.math.ethz.ch/~sudakovb/automorphism.pdf), or earlier [Theorem 2 in this paper](https://link.springer.com/content/pdf/10.1007/BF01895716.pdf).) So any w.h.p. result about $G(n,\frac12)$ extends to a result about almost all unlabeled graphs.

Comment: @MishaLavrov Thanks a lot.  I'll look at the papers.

Answer (score 1):

[OEIS A003216](http://oeis.org/A003216) gives the number of Hamiltonian graphs on $n$ points.  No formula is given, but $a(8)=6196$ says there are $6196$ Hamiltonian graphs on $8$ points.  [OEIS A000088](http://oeis.org/A000088) gives the total number of graphs on $n$ unlabeled points.  For $8$ points there are $12346$ so just over half the graphs on $8$ points are Hamiltonian.  For $12$ points, the highest in the Hamiltonian list, there are $152522187830$ Hamiltonian graphs out of $165091172592$ which would claim that over $92\%$ of the $12$ point graphs are Hamiltonian.

For $n=2$ there are two graphs, neither of which is Hamiltonian.  For $n \lt 8$ over half the graphs are not Hamiltonian.  It doesn't seem surprising to me that once $n$ gets large most graphs are Hamiltonian.  If you think about the complete graph on $n$ vertices you need very few of the edges to make a Hamiltonian path.